# Suddenly got DNS problem with OSX 10.9.2

Tags: dns, internet

I have OSX 10.9.2. One day my internet started to stuck on loading.

No System updates detected before.

When I tried to send ping to `http://stackoverflow.com/` I got:

```
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=54 ttl=47 time=297.871 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 55
Request timeout for icmp_seq 56
Request timeout for icmp_seq 57
Request timeout for icmp_seq 58
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=59 ttl=47 time=149.727 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=60 ttl=47 time=147.736 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=61 ttl=47 time=160.763 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=62 ttl=47 time=148.458 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 63
Request timeout for icmp_seq 64
Request timeout for icmp_seq 65
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=66 ttl=47 time=147.925 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 67
Request timeout for icmp_seq 68
Request timeout for icmp_seq 69
Request timeout for icmp_seq 70
Request timeout for icmp_seq 71
Request timeout for icmp_seq 72
Request timeout for icmp_seq 73
Request timeout for icmp_seq 74
Request timeout for icmp_seq 75
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=76 ttl=47 time=160.432 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=77 ttl=47 time=168.872 ms
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=78 ttl=47 time=160.564 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 79
Request timeout for icmp_seq 80
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=81 ttl=47 time=169.759 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 82
Request timeout for icmp_seq 83
Request timeout for icmp_seq 84
Request timeout for icmp_seq 85
Request timeout for icmp_seq 86
Request timeout for icmp_seq 87
Request timeout for icmp_seq 88
Request timeout for icmp_seq 89
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=90 ttl=47 time=241.351 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 91
Request timeout for icmp_seq 92
64 bytes from 198.252.206.140: icmp_seq=93 ttl=47 time=156.303 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 94
Request timeout for icmp_seq 95
```

However ping to `8.8.8.8` works well (0.2% loss)

What I did so far:

- restart MAC
- restart Router
- other PC Windows 7 works fine
- created hotspot with iPhone and used cellular data - have the same losses

Sounds like OSX has problem with DNS.

Im nubby in OSX, please from where do I need to start investigate the issue?

**[EDIT]**

My DNS settings below:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're confident it's a DNS issue and not a NIC (network interface card, e.g. AirPort vs. Ethernet) issue, then try the following:

- Flush DNS with `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` via http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5343.
- Manually change your DNS server to something else, e.g. 8.8.8.8.  Do that using the "+" button next in the DNS pane you're showing in your post, the button next to "IPv4 or IPv6 addresses."